# Booting up my PC oddly skips the part where I can go into the BIOS?

Tags: boot, bios

When I try to boot up my screen says out of range for a while then goes into Windows (Windows 10) entirely skips the part where I can access the BIOS.

So new problem. First boot it just stays out of range forever after forcing shutdown and then booting up again it boots.

And no matter how much I spam the BIOS key it never boots into the BIOS.

Comment: Can you show us a photo of your out of range error?

Comment: I mean it is not an error per se but it just that the startup directly goes into windows it just skips the gigabyte screen

Comment: Windows 10?????

Comment: @arcana - What operating system?  If you are running Windows 10 you have to use Advance Startup to access the device's the firmware settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running anything above Windows 7, there most likely is a feature called Fast Boot enabled, which can bypass some BIOS/UEFI systems. Disable this in the control panel and perform a full restart and this should fix it.

Comment: Fast Boot should not be disabled.  The author will see a significant increase in the amount of time it takes to boot their device if they do that.  The author should instead, simply use Advanced Startup, and boot into the firmware settings for the device.

Answer (score 0):

How you get into the bios is completely up to the motherboard/hardware manufacturer although with a UEFI bios, Windows 10 can also take you there using the advice above.

What if it won't boot?  Windows 10 certainly won't take you there.

If it is a name brand (like Dell or HP), you can google something like "dell optiplex bios keys".

If it is a home-built, you will need to refer to the motherboard manual or do the same search for the motherboard.

It will involve a fury of (magic) keystrokes right at power on.  For instance.. on >MY< Dell.. I have to pound F2 over and over.

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a really good solution for this.

1. First, use hdmi port, some motherboards go on hdmi first and display port last priority. Even then, boot screen will be skipped if you have fast boot.
2. So, what you gonna do is go to restart in the shutdown options and press it with shift (Alternatively, you can go to advanced start and press restart now), then you reach pxe (windows preexecution environment), from there troubleshoot, and uefi firmware settings. So you come to the bios first. Make sure you have hdmi on and for higher success probability, disconnect all other connections like display port or dvi you have at the moment
3. So, you are in bios now. From there, there should be a fast startup button somewhere. In my msi bios, there was one right at the start page, otherwise search it in the advanced settings.
4. Finally you can start with msi logo screen turning up, but solely on hdmi. Be sure to connect via hdmi when starting up and press del button (i heard it is del for most msi boards, on my previous asus it was f2, but i did not have no bios startup problems there) when you reach msi logo screen. I always connect hdmi if I want to go into bios, there is no other way around for me.

And voila, you can go straight into bios (with hdmi).